# Open in new tab (target="blank")

Tags: html, hyperlink

I would like to open a page in a new tab, using `target="blank"`. Where would I put that?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function gotoURL() {
var newURL = ("http://tulyita.hu/pr2info.php?name=" + document.url2go.go.value)
document.location.href=newURL
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<pre><center>

<form action="javaScript:gotoURL()" method="get" name="url2go">
<input type="text" name="go" value="" size="50">
<input type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>

<title>PR2 Checker GIF</title>
</center></body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: <head><base target="_blank" /></head> or inline target="_blank"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this in your JavaScript function:

```
window.open("http://tulyita.hu/pr2info.php?name=" + document.url2go.go.value, "_blank");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
<form action="javaScript:gotoURL()" target="_blank" method="get" name="url2go">
```

Although some browsers handles this case depends up to the settings. For example in IE9 you may need to change the setting of the browser.

or modify yoour function like this:-

```
 function gotoURL() {
 var newURL = ("http://tulyita.hu/pr2info.php?name=" + document.url2go.go.value)
 window.open(newURL,'_blank');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function to

```
function gotoURL() {
    var newURL = "http://tulyita.hu/pr2info.php?name=" + document.url2go.go.value;
    window.open(newURL, "_blank");
}
```